# Where does Jenkins fit in the devops pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, devops

I don't know where could I fit the jenkins tool in the following devops pipeline:

code -> integrate -> test -> release -> deploy -> operate

Maybe it can be in every steps ?

Comment: Jenkins is a plugin manager, can use it for any stage of your pipeline, ex. **GIT Plugin** to checkout code, **Ant Plugin** to build, **Ansible Plugin** (ansible playbooks) for  integration tests and packaging, **Artifact Repository Plugin** for deploying artifacts to a repository manager, etc.

Comment: **Correction**: Jenkins is not a simple **plugin manager**. Jenkins is an open source implementation of a **Continuous Integration Server** written in Java.

Comment: @JRichardsz thanks but no thanks? Jenkins is (among other things if you want) a plugin manager and “Plugins are the primary means of enhancing the functionality of a Jenkins environment to suit organization- or user-specific needs.”, ref. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/

Comment: From [jenkins.io](https://jenkins.io/): The leading open source automation server, Jenkins provides hundreds of plugins to support building, deploying and automating any project.

Comment: @masseyb what is firefox for you? For me is a super cool browser based on multiples plugins and other functionalities over chrome u opera.  With firefox, you can manage plugins (configure, install, delete, etc) but is not a plugin manager. Jenkins is a Continuous Integration Server or automation server based on a large number of integrated and comunity plugins. Check jenkins home page : https://jenkins.io

Comment: @JRichardsz you enhance your browsing experience by installing plugins i.e. ad-block in the same way you can enhance your Jenkins instances capabilities by installing various plugins. Both are plugin managers whereas “you can manage plugins: install, delete, configure, etc.” and the plugins “enhance the core functionality”..

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins is a build factory. In other words, its primary use is to run tasks that dedicated to build, integrate and deliver applications. It's a typical *DEVOPS* tool.

Jenkins can be used to build pipelines (sequences of tasks) or to be called from a pipeline (to execute one of the pipeline's tasks).

The great thing about Jenkins is that it integrates nicely with other devops tools:

- SCM: SVN, Github, Gitlab
- Build: maven, gradle
- Test: Cucumber reports
- Quality: SonarQube
- Deployment: Octopus Deploy, XL Deploy, Run Deck...

You name it!

However, Jenkins is generally not used to "code" and "operated" applications.

A typical pipeline would be:

```
Try Pull Request => Build Release Candidate => Deploy RC on Integration => Deploy on Production
```

This is a over simplified pipeline, just to give an idea of the scope of this tool. A production grade piepline should include security checks, and integrate nicely with human validation when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins is use for the Build, Test, and Deploy stages of the continuous delivery pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

You can have "n" number of stages in a pipeline that can be configured using Jenkins.

Stages as follows (example) :-

> code -> integrate -> test -> release -> deploy -> operate

Answer (score 1):

Currently in the business sector Jenkins is used as follows:

If you are a **software developer** you need Jenkins for two reasons:

- To build your project and check that it completes all the requirements concerning the pmd rules, checkstyles, findbugs, etc.
- To deploy a new environment so to evaluate yourself. You need to see that the changes you made are the proper one and as you wanted them to be.

If you are a **tester or a test automation engineer** you want it two three reasons:

- To build your code and check for findbugs, pmds and qaplugs generally
- To test the software product, of the client or of your company's product
- To create dynamic environments so to test the changes of the developers (mostly as a regression testing and not as an individual)

If you are a **business related, project manager or supervisor** you can do the next two actions:

- Execute the tests so that you can see yourself if the product is working properly
- Check the reports that Jenkins can give you every after test execution

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is an opensource automation server. Earlier it used to be a CI server only but after Jenkins 2.0, Pipeline as Code has made it popular for CI/CD both. It can manage all application lifecycle phases.